# JS Error + asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to change

```
document.all["SearchCritera" + id + "$ddlFilter"].selectedIndex = 0;
```

to

```
$('SearchCriteria' + id + '$ddlFilter')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

but I get a js error (unable to set value of the property 'selectedIndex': object is null or undefined).  Any ideas how to fix this?  I'm at a complete loss, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
$('#' + 'SearchCriteria' + id + '_ddlFilter')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) jQuery method. Also, it looks like you're directly referencing an element ID, so make sure you prefix your selector with a `#`.

```
$('#SearchCriteria' + id + '$ddlFilter').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```

Although this appears to be not worth the effort, as [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById) exists for this purpose:

```
document.getElementById('SearchCriteria' + id + '$ddlFilter').selectedIndex = 0;
```

*Also, I'm assuming you're using jQuery, but if you're not let me know and I will adjust.*

Comment: I am asking this only to learn. How are `$('#SearchCriteria' + id + '$ddlFilter').get(0)` and `$('#SearchCriteria' + id + '$ddlFilter')[0]` different?

Comment: @FloydPink: They're probably not any different in this instance as the real issue was the lack of a `#`. But `.get()` just grabs the DOM object less the jQuery wrapper (or so is my understanding).

Comment: @FloydPink: No problem. And in case of curiosity, [see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6JGP/). ;-)

Comment: @Brad, the `get` method when using an parameter results to using the `[]` notation .. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L202-210

Comment: @Brad, I tried both solutions out and I still get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Well

1) We have no way of telling you whether or not your selector is correct because you didn't post your HTML code, however...
2) Instead of using `.selectedIndex = 0` try using `.attr("selectedIndex") = 0`

Comment: I won't down-vote, but are you aware of a) how the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method works, and b) what [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) property is all about?

Comment: @Brad - I was looking off code on this page http://blog.coldfusionpowered.com/?p=110

Comment: When calling .`attr('name')` you're only retrieving the value. To set the value you would place its value in the method call as the second parameter. But all trivial since selectedIndex is a DOM property not an HTML attribute.

Comment: @Brad, you are correct. I should've made the call .attr("selectedIndex", 0) instead -- and I guess it won't work either way =/